# Is there a way to track/record via Google Analytics visitors that visit my site via Flipboard?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, flipboard

I've been sniffing through my Apache log files and noticed hits which mention

```
FlipboardProxy/1.1; +http://flipboard.com/browserproxy
```

Is there a way to track/ID these users via Google Analytics so that I can understand what percentage of my visits are via Flipboard?

Comment: Is flipboard not already showing up in your referrals report?

Comment: Flipboard does not "refer" users to sites, its loads the site within the app.

Answer (score 1):

From what i read on flipboard:

> Flipboard uses a proxy service to fetch, validate, and prepare certain
>   elements of websites for presentation through the Flipboard
>   Application.

Retrieving parts of your website to present it in flipboar, they are not actually real visits to your site.

But if you still want to track those requests in analytics then you would need to write a php that sniffs user agent and trigger a gif request to analytics.

Answer (score 0):

IF they're not showing up in the [Browser & OS Report](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1144432); they're probably not running javascript and/or block GA.

Answer (score 0):

Something along those lines might end up here. Right now it shows data at a snapshot only though.

http://ripl.io/flipboard-analytics/